# How do I fix an endpoint error with flask blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I am learning flask with blueprints and I have the following code example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint, g

bp = Blueprint('language', __name__, url_prefix='/<int:language_id>', static_folder='static')
app = Flask(__name__)


@bp.url_defaults
def add_language_id(endpoint, values):
    if 'language_id' in g:
        values.setdefault('language_id', g.site_id)
    else:
        g.language_id = 1  # English


@bp.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_language_id(endpoint, values):
    g.language_id = values.pop('language_id')


@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')


@bp.route('/lang')
def language():
    return render_template('lang.html')

app.register_blueprint(bp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But I'm getting this error:

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint
>   'language' with values ['language_id']. Did you mean 'language.index'
>   instead?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url_for('language', language_id=1) }}">English</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I correct this error?

Comment: I've noticed you are new to the community and this is your 3rd question (so far) on this topic. I would highly suggest you read up on the documentation for flask and python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the Blueprint name (`language`) in your url link:

From here:

```
bp = Blueprint('language', __name__, url_prefix='/<int:language_id>', static_folder='static')
```

So your link will need to be appended:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('language.language', language_id=1) }}">English</a>
```

I would also suggest naming it something different so it doesn't conflict with any other naming convention you might have.

Comment: You say I name it different. What can I name it?

Comment: @TychkinNikitovich You can make it whatever you want, as long as it makes sense. I just like avoiding potential naming conflicts.